# variables in rand() PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I was trying to create a site like random.org in PHP but when i go to the page i receive an error at the line 36 (the $random = rand($first,$last); How can i solve it? 
here is the code!

```
<form action="numero.php" method="post">

<input type="text" name="first">
<input type="submit" value="last">

</form>


<?php 

function random() {

    $first = $_POST['first'];
    $last = $_POST['last']
    $random = rand($first,$last);
    }

echo random();

 ?>
```

Comment: PHPs psuedo-random number generator lacks reliable entropy to make it even viable for generating the quality of random numbers that random.org provides.

Comment: @j_mcnally

That is true, but he could use the [open ssl extension](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) for this. Also note that Random.org offers truly random numbers, there is no pseudo random generator, which delivers that qualifity.

Comment: I agree, i should rephrase, "NO PSUEDO RANDOM NUMBER GENERATOR" will do what random.org is doing. If you want to create a quality random number generator, you can't use rand()

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a semicolon:

```
$last = $_POST['last']; // <- here you missed it. 
$random = rand($first,$last);
```

Therefore you are seeing an error. To prevent this, you can check the syntax with

```
php -l your_file.php
```

There are more problems with your code, like checking if it is a GET request (and need to show the form) or a POST request (and thus need to process your form data).

Answer (score 0):

The first time you load this page you won't have any `POST` data. So you need to wrap your stuff in an if and test if those variables are set.

```
function random() {

    if(isset($_POST['first'])){
        $first = $_POST['first'];
        $last = $_POST['last'];
    } else {
        $first = 1;
        $last = 10;
    }
    $random = rand($first,$last);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP's built in `rand();` function will only take in numbers as an argument.

Since you are passing the value `last` in your submit button, the function will throw an error.

If you give it a numeric value, this should be solved. Or better, retrieve the data from a hidden field so that you can keep the value inside your button the same.

**EDIT**

As noted above, you are also missing a semicolon (`;`) after your `$_POST['last']`.

Answer (score 0):

`rand($min,$max)` takes integers. By default, the values of `$_POST` are strings. Convert them first:

```
rand(intval($first),intval($last));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at php.net for the function it takes int values. I would suggest you check the post values for the desired types.

Also check the max value as mentioned on php.net also.

Where do you define the post name last?

I don't see it in the form.